# native unit test, debugger performing a remote operation that is taking longer than expected

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2012

I've written what should be a very simple unit test using the Native Unit Test project in Visual Studio 2011 Beta.  The test builds and fails (not unexpectedly), and I need to debug it. When I try to launch the test under the debugger, the debugger never starts, and instead presents this dialog which lingers indefinitely:

[image]

Anyone know what might cause this?  I've never had this problem with previous versions of Visual Studio.

Update:

I've opened an MSDN thread on this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/db3213f8-9658-4470-9e3f-3b67ec954fae

I also opened a connect bug (which apparently was just summarily dismissed): https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/735369/debugger-wont-start-for-native-unit-test#details

Answer (score 0):

I would need to know some more information regarding this issue but it seems like it is possible that the DebugAttachProcess() method in windows isn't returning which can happen in the case that you do not have enough permissions to do so... make sure you run VS as Administrator, also, you can try to debug it in ollydbg to see if it is an executable problem, although it wont give you the source (you're stuck in assembly).